# very basic pygame. trying to stop image snapping to a given angle

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame for a little 2d game, I'm a complete beginner.

an image that moves around on the screen when i use the arrow keys always stops facing in a given direction. right now ive got the direction set to -90 so the image is looks up, but i just want it to stop moving and stay facing the same direction. any help?

ive added the script and image

thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROqDO.png)

```
pygame.init()
display_width = 1000
display_height = 800
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('metal gear python')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

snakeimg = pygame.image.load('snake.png')

snake_width = 96
snake_height = 79


#################################################


def snake(x, y):
    if x_change == 0 and y_change == 0:
        rotation = -90                     #< i want to say rotation = rotation so it stops facing upward when not moving
    elif x_change > 0 and y_change == 0:
        rotation = 180
    elif x_change < 0 and y_change == 0:
        rotation = 0
    elif x_change == 0 and y_change > 0:
        rotation = 90
    elif x_change == 0 and y_change < 0:
        rotation = -90
    elif x_change < 0 and y_change < 0:
        rotation = -45
    elif x_change < 0 and y_change > 0:
        rotation = 45
    elif x_change > 0 and y_change < 0:
        rotation = -135
    elif x_change > 0 and y_change > 0:
        rotation = 135
    gamedisplay.blit(pygame.transform.rotate(snakeimg, rotation), (x, y))


discovered = False
while not discovered:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            discovered = True
        print(event)

    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)
    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0
    snake_speed = 0

    gameExit = False
    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
                discovered = True 
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -3
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 3
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -3
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 3
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
                    x_change = 0
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
                    y_change = 0

        x += x_change
        y += y_change

        gamedisplay.fill(white)
        snake(x, y)

        if x > display_width - snake_width or x < 0:
            gameExit = True

        if y > display_height - snake_height or y < 0:
            gameExit = True

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define some boolean variables before starting the game loop
for example you can do something like this:

```
moving_left = False
moving_right = False
moving_up   = False
moving_down = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
            discovered = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:

                x_change = -3
                moving_left = True
                moving_right = False

                moving_down = False
                moving_down = True

            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 3
                moving_right = True
                moving_left = False                    
                moving_up   = False
                moving_down = False


            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -3
                moving_up   = True
                moving_down = False

                moving_left = False
                moving_right = False


            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 3
                moving_down = True
                moving_up   = False

                moving_left = False
                moving_right = False


        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
                x_change = 0
            elif event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
                y_change = 0

    x += x_change
    y += y_change

    rotation = 0
    if moving_left:
        rotation = 0
    elif moving_right:
        rotation = 180
    elif moving_up:
        rotation = -90
    elif moving_down:
        rotation = 90


    gamedisplay.fill(white)
    gamedisplay.blit(pygame.transform.rotate(snakeimg, rotation), (x, y))
```